# Deleting an object in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a this code in my `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
        Task *deletedTask = [_tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.context deleteObject:deletedTask];
        [_tasks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView reloadData];
```

However, it appears like the object is deleting but it does not. How can I fix this?

Comment: did you also do a [self.context save] ?

Comment: @CSmith No. trying now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's your problem, but the object is not deleted just with `deleteObject` you also need to save it.

Have a look at what [iOS doc says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/06_Deleting.html):

> To delete a record, you tell the managed object context to mark an
>   object as deleted, using the deleteObject: method of
>   NSManagedObjectContext. Then to actually destroy the record, you
>   commit the action using save:.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was save. Thanks @CSmith

```
NSError *error = nil;
[self.context save:&error];
```